# When Java Threads are used in Internet facing Java web application

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been working on high availability internet facing Java web applications using Strurts, Spring, JSF, Hibernate etc. which are being used by multiple end users simultaneously. However, i have never seen code related to threads or multi threads, then how concurrency is achieved ?

When i attend interviews people ask many questions related to multi threading. If thread is really so important then why in none of my application threads were never used.

Need your help to understand the real need of threads in real time web application.

Comment: This is managed by your servlet container/JEE server .

Comment: Of course even if the concurrency is handled by the container and you're not writing explicitly multithreaded code, you're still working in a multithreaded context and need to understand concurrent programming and when it might be relevant.

Comment: I think it is more like thread per session, take a look old ThreadLocal usage examples and imagine a scenario each different thread holds session data which is not visible to others. But also keep in mind it can be implementation specific, i.e. reactive servers like vert-x has different approach

Comment: @HRgiger a thread per *session* approach would be very performance intensive, as long running sessions wouldn't be able to share threads. Session data doesn't need to be threadlocal. You **could** implement it like that, but since it's inefficient, it would be hard to imagine it being used anywhere.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for the tip, what would be the better alternative that is used lately?

Comment: @HRgiger Thread per request. It's been used *always*, not just "lately". What you imagined has never been used.

Comment: @Kayaman I think we have discussed different things, I think what you mention is thread creation/pooling when first http request received, but I was 'imagining' other components like session context or application context that also part of lifecycle, i.e. I remember I saw ThreadLocal usages in spring source code years ago. Now I searched in wildfly repo and found more usages of ThreadLocal https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ThreadLocal&type=

Comment: @HRgiger well most likely we're discussing different things. I never said `ThreadLocal` isn't used anywhere, I was saying that it's not used to implement session storage. A session is not tied to a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why have I never encountered anything related to threads during web application development?

In web applications, threads are automatically managed by your servlet container or JEE server (as mentioned by @Berger). They come with sensible default settings which enables them to work "out of the box".

#### How are threads handled in a typical web application environment?

Every request to the web application is handled by a single thread. For example, if 10 users send a request to the server at the same time, the server will have 10 threads running simultaneously.

The servlet container or JEE server maintains a pool of threads. When a request comes in, a thread is *assigned* to the request to handle it. When the request is done, the thread is *released* back into the pool - ready to be assigned to a new request.

#### Why a thread pool?

In a web application environment, requests are many, short and asynchronous.  Creating a new thread and closing it for each request causes quite a bit of overhead. This is why a bunch of threads are created beforehand - the thread pool - to solve the overhead problem.

Comment: Or it has a thread pool to handle the requests one after the other, allowing for reuse of threads.

Answer (score 0):

In real world behind the scene app server use thread for serving user request.That is why simultaneously the server can serve multiple user.
For an example  Web servers, database servers which  processed  a large number of short tasks that arrive from some remote source. A request arrives at the server in some manner, which might be through a network protocol such as HTTP, FTP . Regardless of how the request arrives, it is often the case in server applications that the processing of each individual task is short-lived and the number of requests is large.One model to serve is  create a new thread each time a request arrives and service the request in the new thread and disadvantages is

```
1.thread-per-request approach is that the overhead of creating a new thread for each request is significant and 

2. Creating too many threads in one JVM can cause the system to run out of memory or thrash due to excessive memory consumption
```

Other model is use thread pool.

Some sever like nodejs and play frame work use single thread event loop to address different use case.